# joomla plugin deactivation event

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

how to call a php function on disabling a plugin in joomla.for example register_deactivation_hook in wordpress. please help me.I want to delete/rewrite some text files on disabling my plugin.Text files are generated at the time of plugin activation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onAfterRender` event.